# Redirecting output to email

Tags: windows, email, redirection

I am aware that in Windows you can use the following snippet to redirect the output of a command line tool to the clipboard:

```
mytool | clip
```

Also, it can be done with files:

```
clip < myFile.txt
```

I also know Windows has several other devices/programs you can use as output / input for these redirections (probably the printer is the most famous of them).

However, is there something to send the text to the default email program?

I would love to find that there is something like: `mytool | email`. Is there something alike?

Comment: Nitpicking: clip in your examples is not a device, it's a program named `clip.exe`

Comment: @wmz Everything counts! Thanks, I'll correct it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [mailto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailto) URL scheme to construct an email link containing a predefined message body, then call it from the command line, which should open it in your default email client. For example:

```
start mailto:?body=Your%20message%20here
```

Just customise the part after `body=` at the end. I've read that the text needs to be [URL-encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_encoding), but at least in Windows Live Mail 2012 that doesn't seem to be necessary. I didn't try with longer texts or special symbols, though, and I don't have any other email clients (Outlook, Thunderbird, etc.) to test with.

For constructing that command, you could write a simple batch file, such as the following one:

```
@echo off
set /p text=
if "%text%" == "" goto error
start mailto:?body=%text%
goto end
:error
echo No argument provided!
:end
```

However, with that you do need the text to be URL-encoded, so you might want to do the whole thing in PowerShell. To URL-encode a string, you can use this:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Web") | out-null
[System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode("Your message here")
```

(The first line is needed to load the `System.Web` namespace where the `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` function lives.)

In fact, if your command (or whatever you have that produces the text you want to redirect) isn't too complex, you can just write the following one-liner in PowerShell (replacing `<your-command-here>` with the actual command you're using):

```
start ("mailto:?body={0}" -f [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode(<your-command-here>))
```

---

Note: this assumes that you just want to redirect text to your default email client. If you want to actually send emails from the command line, then look at @allquixotic's answer.

Comment: This is awesome! Would this work with multiple-lined outputs? (Maybe the new lines are URL encoded... is each line processed in different calls?)

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a possible software solution](http://glob.com.au/sendmail/) although be aware that you can, in principle, write a script of any sort (Ruby, VBscript, Bash, or a program from scratch) to do something similar. There are a variety of ways you can do it, including command line options for the To: and Subject lines, and so on. But that "fake sendmail" just might do what you want.